# Update Set for 20+ million rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table for each month in the year and in that table is (amongst other things) 25 columns for custom data. Only the first 8 data columns are indexed and we have inserted data into column 21 that they now want to do wildcard searches on. I can't create an index for column 21 as the application won't allow wildcard searches on anything but the first 8 data columns in their GUI.

I tried to run the following but it timed out when the transaction log got full, have since changed it to unrestricted growth as it was set to 134 GB max size.

```
UPDATE CentralContact.dbo.Spd_month_1 
SET p1_value = p21_value 
WHERE dbs_id ='190'
```

Is there a faster way of doing this as each table contains over 20 million records?

Comment: You could partition your dataset (eg only do the ones that start with 'A' then 'B' etc )

Comment: See what you mean, although every value in p21 is a unique value but won't be sequential and is random

Comment: Let me understand this correctly.  You want to overwrite data (possibly destroying it) because you can't change the application to add a ninth search field, or change the application to reference `p21_value` instead of `p1_value`?

Comment: first update whole table then `select from table where p1_values <> p21values` and update them; due to lot of load this happend

Comment: Consider using a seperate table for this obvious n:m relation between the table rows and the custom data entries.

Comment: won't be destroying anything as the p1 column is empty, the vendor will not change anything and if we change anything it will invalidate the support agreement.

Answer (score 2):

20 million rows is not a lot of rows, even if you're running on a laptop. I have test tables with a couple of hundred million rows on my Lenovo x1 (SSD + 8GB RAM). My servers have tables (non-partitioned) with several billion rows.

Your update query timing out because of the transaction log getting full isn't really a performance problem. It looks like you either haven't backed up the transaction log recently or the rows are pretty big and is filling up the tlog even with the 1 big transaction. A couple of options to consider:

1. Backup the transaction log to free up space from all previous committed transactions. If you haven't done this recently, its probably the best thing to do now. Look up SQL Server books online for details on how to do this. At 134GB, that's a pretty big tlog and if autogrown since initial creation, you probably have way too many virtual log files and lots of physical fragmentation - both can have significant negative impact on performance (if you're running on SSDs then physical fragmentation is ok). Also, each autogrow gets worse because the Tlog space needs to be initialized before use so you're initializing bigger and bigger chunks. Strong consider wiping out the tlog and recreate at a "reasonable" size from scratch when you get a maintenance window.
2. Break the update into several smaller transactions. This may or may not be easy depending on the rest of the schema. If there is a column with some kind of monotonic value (e.g. timestamp, date, identity, ID, etc...), then you can easily update ranges at a time. Having a column with a small number of unique values is also helpful. Just be careful you don't have a bunch of new values added or updated while you're making the change. If you are not a 24x7 operation, locking the DB in single user mode to do the update and verification is the easiest, though heavy handed, solution.

Comment: To this excellent comment, I would add this:  make sure your database is in simple logging mode  (at least for the duration of this transformation).   Make sure that you read up on the repercussions of doing this, but 145GB of log is a ridiculously large amount;  and unless your individual records are monstrously big, is very likely unjustified.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to do what you want is probably to use views.  First, rename the table and then create a view to munge the columns:

```
sp_rename 'CentralContact.dbo.Spd_month_1 ', '_Spd_month_1'

create view Spd_month_1 as
    select p_col21 as p_col1, . . .
    from _Spd_month_1;
```

The view is pretty simple, so it can be used for updates.  You are not deleting the original table, so constraints, foreign key references, triggers, and the like are preserved.  The application should be able to access the view as easily as the table.

The problem with your update is that every row is changed, so every row gets logged.  This is true even with SQL Server's minimal logging capability.  One way around this problem is to copy the table to another location, truncate it, and re-insert the data.  However, with 134 Gbytes, I would try to minimize any data movement operations.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably going to want to use is Kettle (or "spoon") from Pentaho. Check it out [here](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/).

What this does is has "jobs" and "transformations" and other automated processes that you can have maintain your various servers and databases.

One of the things it does is a bulk update. You can select an entire record set to be updated and then feed it 1000 records every few seconds for it to update and commit. This way it doesn't endlessely lock the table up.

I use this all the time and would never advise using anything else other than this method when doing large updates on heavy traffic / heavy load tables.